# NodeJS assert does not throw passed error

Tags: node.js

I have just started using NodeJS's `assert` Module, and, given that I have understood it correctly, I can pass a custom error instance that should be thrown instead of an `AssertionError` if the assertion fails.

I.e., the first line in the following code throws an `AssertionError` and the second line throws an `Error`:

```js
const assert = require('assert');

assert(false);
assert(false, new Error('abc'));
```

However, on my system, this does not seem to work. I have the following code:

```js
try {
    assert(false, new Error('abc'));
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error.constructor.name);
}
```

and the Output I get is `'AssertionError'`. Interestingly, when I try to do the same thing using the REPL, the output is the expected `'Error'`.

I use NodeJS v15.8.0 in an alpine Docker container.

Comment: what version of Node?

Comment: As stated in my question, I use NodeJS v15.8.0.

Comment: works perfectly fine in runkit: https://runkit.com/coagmano/runkit-npm-assert-custom-error

Comment: Looks like this works from Node 9 and up, so you should have no issue with Node 15 

Comment: I found the error (but not a solution). One important piece of information that I left out was, that I was running the code within a Jest unit test and Jest seems to mess with assert. See this issue: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7547

Comment: Did you find a solution @Lehks ?

Comment: @htulipe No, unfortunately not. And as you can see, the linked issue in my previous comment is still open with no further developments. I have settled with using a custom assert function.